# Error in Until section

Tags: algorithm2e

I'm newbie for tex. I am writing an algorithm in tex, I need some help in troubleshooting the error.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{algpseudocode}
\usepackage[linesnumbered]{algorithm2e}
\title{Apriori Algorithm}
\author{Mohan}

\begin{document}
\maketitle

\section{Algorithm}
\IncMargin{1em}
\begin{algorithm}[H]

\Indp
 $k$ = 1\;
 $F_{k}\ =\ \{\ i\ |\ i\ \in\ I \land \sigma\{i\}\ \geq\ N\ \ast \ minsup  \}$\;
 \Repeat{ 
  $k$ = $k$ + 1\;
  $C_k\ =\ apriori-gen(F_{k-1}).$\ \ \ \{Generate Candidate itemsets\}\;
  \For{$each\ transaction\ t\ \in\ T \ \do$}{
    $C_{t}\ =\ subset(C_{k},t).$\ \ \{Identify all candidates that belong to t\}\;
     \For{$each\ candidate\ itemset\ c \in C_{t} \do$}{
    $\sigma(c)=\sigma(c)\ +\ 1$\ \ \ \{Increment support count\}\;
     }
  }
  $F_{k}=\{ c|c\in C_{k}\land\sigma(c) \geq N\ \ast\ minsup\}$\{Extract the frequent k-itemsets\}\;
  }
  \Until{$F_{k}=\emptyset$}
  Result = $F_{k}$\;

\caption{Frequent itemset generation of the Apriori algorithm}
\end{algorithm}
\DecMargin{1em}
\end{document}
```

Thanks

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. Which error(s) are you getting? And, which TeX distribution do you use?

Comment: It seems that the correct syntax for a repeat-until-loop is simply `\Repeat{<untilcond>}{<loop body>}` without the need for a `\Until` command, so you would have `\Repeat{$F_{k}=\emptyset$}{`... and then *no* `\Until`.

Comment: Note also that you should use `$k = k + 1$` instead of jumping in and out of math mode all the time as in `$k$ = $k$ + 1`. Text in math mode should be wrapped in `\text{}`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `\Repeat` command as defined by `algorithm2e` does not come with a complementary `\Until` command, it has the aborting condition built in: The syntax is

```
\Repeat{<untilcond>}{<loop body>}
```

In your example that would be

```
\Repeat{$F_{k}=\emptyset$}{
   $k = k + 1$\;
}
```